# XML XSD validation based on parent element?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Is it possible to validate XML node in XSD file "conditionally"?  That is, validate it based on parent node name?

For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rootNode>
  <parentA>
    <value>Some text</value>
  </parentA>
  <parentB>
    <value>Some text</value>
  </parentB>  
</rootNode>
```

Validation for `value` used in `parentA` would look like:

```xml
<xs:element name="value">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
      <xs:minLength value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Validation for `value` used in `parentB` would be different:

```xml
<xs:element name="value">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="4"/>
      <xs:minLength value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, even in XSD 1.0, locally declared elements can vary in type according to the context provided by the parent element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="rootNode">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ParentA">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="value">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
                    <xs:minLength value="0"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ParentB">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="value">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="4"/>
                    <xs:minLength value="0"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The `value` element within `ParentA` has a different type than the `value` element within `ParentB`.